# Python, curl, and double data

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to write a Python version of a curl call. The problem I'm having is that the curl requires two "--data" sections. How is that done in Python?

Here is the documentation for the curl command:

```
curl "https://example.com/v1/doThing"
-u your-api-key:x
--request POST
--data mode=merge
--data data={ JSON settings object }
```

I've been using something like this for other, non-double-data APIs, but I'm not sure what to do with the double-data.

```
r = requests.post(url, auth=(myToken,"password"), data=settingsJson)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests module can accommodate what you are looking to do by either using a tuple or dictionary. As an example, below I've passed in the `settings_json` dictionary into a parent `data` dictionary.

You could try something like the following:

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/v1/doThing'

settings_json = {
    'name': 'bob',
    'age': 57
}

data = {
    'mode': 'merge',
    'json_data': settings_json
}

r=requests.post(url, auth=(myToken,'password'), data=data)
```

If this doesn't work for your use case then you can always consult the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for additional examples.

The exact request format will depend on how your server is configured to receive this data.

[This](https://curl.trillworks.com/#) is also a helpful tool for converting `curl` requests to other languages.